# with grapejs - did "npm start", but localhost:8080 will say This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect

Tags: node.js

I downloaded the zip (from https://github.com/artf/grapesjs) and unzipped, then did the "npm i" command.  That tooks a while, then I ran "npm start" and the console displayed this:

e:\GitHub\NealWalters\GrapeJSDemo>npm start

> grapesjs@0.14.5 start e:\GitHub\NealWalters\GrapeJSDemo
>   npm run build:css -- -w & webpack-dev-server --open --progress --colors
>
> grapesjs@0.14.5 build:css e:\GitHub\NealWalters\GrapeJSDemo
>   node-sass src/styles/scss/main.scss dist/css/grapes.min.css --output-style compressed "-w"

When I try http://localhost:8080 in the browser, I get the error: 
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

Here is my directory structure: 
[image]

I have run other NodeJS programs before with success. Running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

On `npm start`, the process gets bound to watching files and doesn't reach the next command to startup the server. Try adding `start` in the beginning of the `start` script to run a separate process for watching the files. Then the command to startup the server will get executed.

So in `package.json`, change the `start` script to the following:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "start npm run build:css -- -w & webpack-dev-server --open --progress --colors"
}
```

Comment: Marking as correct, but I've moved on to other projects now.